# SQL storing MD5 in char column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column of type char(32) where I want to store an MD5 hash key. The problem is i've used SQL to update the existing records using HashBytes() function which creates values like

```
:›=k! ©úw"5Ýâ‘<\
```

but when I do the insert via .NET it comes through as

```
3A9B3D6B2120A9FA772235DDE2913C5C
```

What do I need to do to get these to match up? Is it the encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HashKey isn't a SQL function, did you mean `HASHBYTES`? Some actual code would help. SQL appears to be computing the raw binary hash and displaying it as ASCII characters.

.NET is computing the hash, then converting it to hexadecimal (or so it appears). CHAR(32) isn't a good way to store raw binary data, you would want to use the BINARY type.

An Example in SQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(sys.fn_varbintohexstr(HASHBYTES('MD5',0x2040)),3, 32)
```

And an Example in .NET:

```
using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    var data = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x40 };
    var hashed = md5.ComputeHash(data);
    var hexHash = BitConverter.ToString(hashed).Replace("-", "");
    Console.Out.WriteLine("hexHash = {0}", hexHash);
}
```

These will both produce the same value. (Where 0x2040 is sample data).

You can either store the hexadecimal data as CHAR(32), or as BINARY(16). Storing the Binary data is twice as space efficient than storing it as hex. What you should not be doing is storing the binary data as CHAR(16).

Comment: switched to binary instead of char and it's all working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "when I do the insert via .NET" - but you *shouldn't* be storing binary data just in a raw form, as it looks like your'e doing using `HashKey()`. (Do you definitely mean `HashKey` by the way? I can't find a reference for it, but there's `HashBytes`...)

Two common options are to encode the raw binary data as hex - which it looks like you're doing in the second case - or to use base64. Either way should be easy from .NET (Base64 marginally easier, using `Convert.ToBase64String`) and you probably just need to find the equivalent SQL Server function.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is typically stored as in hex encoding. I'd guess that your hashkey() SQL function is not hex encoding the MD5 hash, rather it's just returning the ASCII characters representing the hash. But your .NET method is HEX encoding. If you store your MD5 hashing consistently as HEX (or not - up to you but usually stored as HEX), then the results between the two should always be consistent.

For example, the : symbol from your SQL hash is the first character returned from HashKey(). In the .NET method, the first 2 characters are 3A. 31 is 51 in decimal. ASCII code 51 is the colon (:) character. Similarly, you can work your way through each other character, and do the HEX conversion.

See any ASCII codes table for reference, i.e. http://www.asciitable.com/